# Add custom icon to ShortCutItem in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiapplicationshortcutitem

I've searched a lot but don't find a solution for my problem...

```
let test = UIMutableApplicationShortcutItem(
            type: "testtype",
            localizedTitle: "Title",
            localizedSubtitle: "Subtitle",
            icon: UIApplicationShortcutIcon(type: .add),
            userInfo: nil)
```

My problem is that I have an image in my `Assets` folder and I want to use it as icon in the `ShortCutItem`. If you add a Shortcut in `info.plist` you can use `UIApplicationShortcutItemIconFile` to set a custom icon - how can I make that in Swift?

This doesn't work:

```
icon: UIApplicationShortcutItemIconFile(type: .TITLEOFIMG),
```

Thanks for all help!

Comment: Use the `UIApplicationShortcutIcon(templateImageName: xxx)` initializer

Comment: Thanks, but I get the "Use of unresolved identifier 'img_name'" error. Any idea?

Comment: Testing before asking... I missed the String quotes in the image-name. Now it works - thank you!